# Laptop shuts down without warning when on battery irrespective of OS

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, shutdown

I have an HP laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 both installed in dual boot mode. When I'm working on the laptop with battery power, the laptop shuts down without any warning irrespective of the OS I'm working in. This never happens when I'm working on AC power, so I don't think that overheating is the culprit here. Moreover, when I switch on the laptop after the abrupt shutdown the battery percentage is usually a good value (>50%). When I checked the battery with the HP diagnostics tool it showed that battery was becoming weak but what I'm not able to understand is that even though it is weak the indicator should go down as the battery is drained and give a warning at 10%. If the battery has become weak, the 10% mark will just be achieved faster. This is what happened with my previous battery and from that I was able to judge that since the draining time has decreased the battery needs to be replaced. But, that does not happen here. So can it be a problem with the battery indicator in both the OS giving me the wrong value? If yes, then is this an issue that can be solved by replacing the battery or is it something to do with the laptop? Also, if replacing the battery can solve the issue what might be the problem that this issue is occurring for this battery and did not happen for the last one? I had bought this battery from the official HP store.

Comment: Most likely a dead battery - at least one cell is damaged. It happens randomly.

Comment: Could also be a loose connection between the battery pack and the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the battery cell is damaged. Now this is a guess I made from repairing my laptop battery by replacing one damaged cell. So there are multiple connection from the battery pack going to different components each having different operating voltages. However, the battery % shown is the total for the battery pack. When one cell is week and completely drains before other cells, it cuts the power supply to those components powered by that cell and the system shuts down. However, since other cells are all healthy, the total battery % shown will remain high.
The solution ma be to replace all cells (if you can repair the battery yourself) or buy a new battery pack.